# Is this tire damaged? (ran on flat)

Tags: tires, safety, sidewall

Flat and after-flat pics (it was installed on the other side after flat...  I think)

[image]

[image]

Ran about 70 meters (76 yards) at very-very low speed with this tire completely flat, it only has 2000 miles on it, does it need replacing? Do I need to replace both back tires (RWD)? The tire is not a run-flat.

Also I may have run with it days before while it was low, but I don't think so because the sensors didn't say anything and I didn't feel anything strange.

Answer (score 2):

A tire with that large a profile would likely survive running ~70 yards completely flat, although presumably it will have been running for some distance *partially* flat and this is the unknown that may have caused damage to the sidewalls.

The problem with damage from running "flat" or even *partially* flat is that the damage is done internally - you can't generally see it from the outside so a tire may look perfectly healthy but be one good bump away from failing spectacularly.

The only way to be sure is to have the tire taken off the rim and inspected - this isn't a long job and if you've got a tire fitter you trust they should be able to do this for you in a matter of minutes for the cost of what they would charge to fit a tire.

As an aside tires don't generally go flat - especially not quickly for no reason, do you know what the original cause of the flat was and has *that* been addressed?

Comment: Hello and thanks for the response. The cause was a sharp screw and it has been patched from the inside. The guy that patched it at the tire shop..i don't think he had any qualification but didn't mention anything strange.. As you can see..some of the sidewall is faded as in you can no longer tell what figures are there and also in the Michelin mascot area (the michelin head is faded). They have 2000 miles..

Comment: Any damage to the inside of the tire *should* have been obvious to the guy who took it off to patch it - it's usually pretty hard to miss. So unless he was a complete incompetent you should be good to go!